# How start virtual machines as a job in powershell azure

Tags: azure, powershell

Im working on a powershell script which starts multiple as jobs i have tried this

```
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "Test2" -Name "tux" -AsJob true
```

but all i got was this error message :
Stop-AzureRmVM : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AsJob'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to execute the command like below if you want to start the VM as a job:

```
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "Test2" -Name "tux" -AsJob
```